# logstash: using multiple elapsed filters

Tags: filter, logstash, elapsed, logstash-configuration

So I've been busy with timing the time difference between some events, and came across an instance where two tasks are stopped with the same event, however, when calling the elapsed plugin twice, only the first is recorded. What should I do to make elapsed record both?

Example config:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => ["message", "STARTING TASK1: (?.)"]
    add_tag => [ "Task1Started" ]
  }
  grok {
    match => ["message", "STARTING TASK2: (?.)"]
    add_tag => [ "Task2Started" ]
  }
  grok {
    match => ["message", "ENDING ALL TASKS: (?.)"]
    add_tag => [ "Task1Terminated", "Task2Terminated"]
  }
  elapsed {
    start_tag => "Task1Started"
    end_tag => "Task1Terminated"
    unique_id_field => "task_id"
  }
  elapsed {
    start_tag => "Task2Started"
    end_tag => "Task2Terminated"
    unique_id_field => "task_id"
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help on this issue!
I also put this question on : https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-elapsed/issues/13

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a different [unique_id_field](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/elapsed#unique_id_field) in each elapsed filter